# Number/ Position of a Comment

Tags: comments

Does anyone know a good way to get the count number or position of a comment under a post?

In the known comment array there is only the `related_post_ID` not the relative number in the affected post.

Of course within a comment loop I can make some `$i++` stuff, but if i only got the ID of a comment - how do i get the "position" in all comments of its related posting?

Is there a WordPress function for this?